# Joomla 3.9.1 publish/unpublish no longer working (custom components)

Tags: joomla3.0

I've recently upgraded my joomla site to 3.9.1, and now my custom components publish/unpublish buttons aren't working and I can't figure out why. The database column is called "state" and this is the code which was working up until the upgrade:

```
JToolbarHelper::publish('items.publish', 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH', true);
JToolbarHelper::unpublish('items.unpublish', 'JTOOLBAR_UNPUBLISH', true);
```

These buttons used to work and they would publish / unpublish the items, now I get this message:

**0 items successfully published**

I'm not sure where exactly the code is which tells it to update the status of the item, but for some reason it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add following line to the __construct function within "table" file:

```
$this->setColumnAlias('published', 'state');
```

so it looks like

```
public function __construct(&$db) 
{
    parent::__construct('#__your_custom_table', 'id', $db);
    $this->setColumnAlias('published', 'state');
}
```

Works for my custom component.